# Slope Formula Approaches Value of Derivative at a Point

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I came across this question while helping a friend study for an Analysis exam; Analysis is not exactly my forte, so maybe I'm missing something obvious, I don't know:

> Suppose $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at some point $c\in
>  (a,b)$ (no other assumptions on $f$ other than differentiability at $c$) (it may have said $c\in [a,b]$, which I suppose would add a
>    case to examine,  but we can stick to $c$ in the open interval). Prove
>    that, for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that
>    $0<|x-y|<\delta$ and $a\leq x\leq c\leq y\leq b$ imply that
>   $\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}-f^\prime (c)\right|<\epsilon$.

Now, the geometric picture makes it obvious to me that this should be true, but maybe the mechanics of the proof have me confused. That $f^\prime(c)$ exists means that $\lim\limits_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$ exists, and we could write out the definition of limit here which would *almost* coincide with what we are asked to prove, but not quite. So I thought about looking directly at the expression $\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}-f^\prime (c)\right|$ and seeing what could be done... I tried adding and subtracting $f(c)$ from the numerator of the slope formula, and getting $\left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-y}+\frac{f(c)-f(y)}{x-y}-f^\prime (c)\right|$, which almost seems like something that I could work with, but it seems I would want $x-c$ and $c-y$ to be the denominators, respectively; it's certainly true that $|x-y|$ must be greater than or equal to each of $|x-c|$ and $|c-y|$, maybe allowing some sort of inequality to be asserted, but something about the signs of the numerators makes me question the validity of the assertion. The Triangle Inequality may be of some use, but it didn't work out quite right (I found myself wanting two copies of $f^\prime(c)$, as well as the aforementioned issue with the inequalities involving replacing denominators in the first place).

I also considered using a different version of the difference quotient (namely, $\frac{f(c+h)-f(c-h)}{2h}$), but it only seemed to help in the case where $|x-c|=|y-c|$, and even then I don't think the proof was complete.

So, I feel that the result seems so obvious that I must be missing something easy, but I cannot seem to figure out what that is. Would anyone care to provide a solution, or at least point me in the right direction? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Differentiability is not defined at the extremes; open interval is the correct hypothesis.

Comment: Could you not define left or right differentiability (i.e., the derivative from the right of f(x) = |x| is 1, and from the left is -1)? In any case, the open interval hypothesis is fine, that's not really my sticking point.

Comment: My previous comment should refer to left/right derivatives of |x| at x=0 (obviously haha).